# Additional Conditional Iteration State and Task View Restriction in TFS 2017

Tags: tfs

I am new to Team Foundation Server (TFS 2017). I want to create an additional iteration state called “QA Passed”. Which will be controlled by only Test user. Also, I can see when a particular user login into TFS local web portal then he can see all other tasks in iteration Backlog/Kanban board. 
Now how can I

1. Create an additional state in iteration which will be controlled by
   only Test users
2. Restrict a particular user viewing other tasks and view only to his
   specific tasks.

I will be very happy to get solutions on this regards. Thanks.

Comment: You can specify the iteration (view iteration node permission) and area permission (view work item). Is it meet your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that please follow below steps:

For question 1:

1. Click the gear icon to navigate to manage page
2. Select ‘**Work**’ tab > **Iterations** > **New** iteration called “QA Passed”
3. Click the ‘**…**’ behind ‘QA Passed ’ > **Security**
4. Select the Test Users who will control the iteration and set ‘**View permissions for this node**’ to Allow.

For question 2:

1. Switch to **Areas** tab
2. Click the ‘**…**’ behind the specific area  > Security
3. Select the specific users and set ‘**View work items in this node**’ to **Allow** and **Deny** for the Restrict users.
   [image]